# Remover Marker en Especifico Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

Tengo la siguiente consulta, estoy creando una App que agregar varios Markers en el mapa, hasta ahi todo bien, pero a la hora que quiero modificar desde la base de datos la ubicacion de uno de los marker, el sistema no sabe cual Marker es el que tiene que mover.

De casualidad hay alguna manera de ponerles un id unico a los marker, o crear algun tipo de variable dinamica, que me permita identificar a cual marker corresponde.

```
    double latitud = Double.parseDouble(lat);
    double longitud = Double.parseDouble(lon);

   LatLng coordenadasBuses = new LatLng(latitud,longitud);
   MarkerOptions().position(coordenadasBuses).title(idBuses));
    if (market != null){
        market.remove();
    }

   market= MainActivity.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(coordenadasBuses)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker())
    );
```

la variable Market es una variable Global, por lo que solo se utiliza esta variable para agregar los Marker, se que ese es un error, porque el no sabe cual de los market tiene que eliminar.

Gracias por cualquier aporte.

Comment: No son "Market", son "Marker" (marcadores)

Comment: Lo primero, el marker no debería ser global, deberías crear uno para cada marcador y así, le puedes asignar en su propiedad Tag lo que quieras, un id, un objeto... que podrás recuperar al hacer click sobre el

Comment: debes tener una lista con los marcadores ya que si usas solo una variable global, se refiere al último que insertas

Answer (score 1):

Primero obtienes el String del id de tu base de datos:

```
String id = Long.toString(TUCOLUMNA_ID); //de SQLite
String id = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString(ID))); // de MySql
```

Comparas ese string y agregas el marcador que quieras, como en este caso 2 colores diferentes:

```
if ("1".equals(id)) {
 mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(title).rotation(0).snippet(title + "\n" + "ejemplo de marker")
 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));

   }else if ("2".equals(id)){
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(title).rotation(0).snippet("otro ej")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    } else if (...
```